# How Do I Make My Input Fields Black and Text to Blue

Tags: html, css

```html
<form method="post" action="https://ip/form.php">
First name<br> <input type="text" name="fname" value=""><br>
Email Address:<br> <input type="text" name="email" value=""><br>
Phone: <br> <input type="text" name="phone" value=""><br><br>

<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="Sign up" value="Sign up">

</form>
```

My input fields are white.  So is the text.  User can't see their inputs.
How do I change the input field to black and input text to blue?
Also, how do I change the submit button to black.

Many thanks, sorry I don't know this stuff better yet.

Comment: Downvoted for providing 0 context. Your input fields where? What did you try? What does vim have anything to do with this? Please edit your question and/or provide more context next time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my code in the original post. I am using vim to code, I needed more tags so I used vm.

Comment: Hey @JesseWilliamMacDougall , welcome to stack overflow. Your question is a bit confusing. Here is a guide to format questions in a way that will make it easier for you to get a more helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

**try this**
on `<style>` tag you can change  ( black , white ,blue ) to any other color

```html
<style>
    .text{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    body{
     color:blue;
    }
</style>
<form method="post" action="https://ip/form.php">
    First name<br> <input class="text" type="text" name="fname" value=""><br>
    Email Address:<br> <input class="text" type="text" name="email" value=""><br>
    Phone: <br> <input class="text" type="text" name="phone" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="Sign up" value="Sign up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

A code snippet along with the description is always a better option. Anyway, you can use inline css.

```
<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" style="background-color: #000; color: blue;"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: black;">
</form>
```

Or else you can also use class or id attribute with tags and you can simply define styles inside  tag. Like,

```
<style>
#fname{
   background-color: black;
   /*Other Styles*/
}
#sButton{
    background-color: black;
   /*Other Styles*/
}
</style>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" id=''fname" name="fname"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="sButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome this worked! Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

**Hey, before I answer this question I just want to point out that you really need to lay out your questions a bit better. I got my account practically banned a while ago because a load of jerks "weren't pleased by the layout".** Just a heads up!

If you want to change the color of your input box add a `style="color: [your color];"` to your HTML tag, e.g:

```
<input type="text" style="background-color: [your color];">
```

you can use `placeholder="[text]"` and

```
::-ms-input-placeholder {color: [your color];}
```

to change the color of the placeholder (the text in the box before the user begins to type) in your in input

And if you want to change the text color altogether use `color` like this:

```
<input type="text" style="color: [your color];">
```

easy :)

P.S I only got the privilege to post back today so sorry if the question isn't layed out top quality!

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple to do.

```
input[type=text] {
  background: black;
  color: blue;
}
```

This will only target the input fields with `type` set to `'text'`.
In the example below, We change the button background color and text color.

```css
input[type=text] {
  background: black;
  color: blue;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://ip/form.php">
First name<br> <input type="text" name="fname" value=""><br>
Email Address:<br> <input type="text" name="email" value=""><br>
Phone: <br> <input type="text" name="phone" value=""><br><br>

<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="Sign up" value="Sign up">

</form>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 0 context in your question, so just going by your tags... (Which are confusing too, by the way. What does styling your website have anything to do with vim?)

Use `color: black;` CSS for text color. `background-color: blue;` changes the background color. Optionally use `border: none;` to remove borders which may or may not be there   by default depending on your browser.